# Getting user friendly messages back to the View

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

This is a summary of how a user would login in my application(up to validating the data):

1. Submit the login form.
2. Router figures out where the user is trying to go.
3. The correct `Controller` is initialized.
4. The `RecognitionService` is started and the `login()` method is run.
5. Within the `login()` method I set the supplied username and password in my `User` domain object.
6. My `User` domain object will check if the username and password are
   valid by checking their type, length, format etc.

All this is good except for when the entered username contains invalid characters and then getting the error message from my domain object back to the `View` in a neat and tidy way.

At the moment I am having my domain objects return the message (well really the array key to the message) to the `RecognitionService` which then holds onto the message array key and then in the `View` I retrieve the message array key from the `RecognitionService` and use it to display the correct message but I have a feeling there is a better way of doing it, any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller and current view should share the same factory for instantiating services, which ensures that each service is initialized only once.

From controller:

```
public function postLogin( $request )
{
    $recognition = $this->serviceFactory->create('Recognition');
    $recognition->authenticate( $request->getParameter('username'),
                                $request->getParameter('password') );
}
```

From view:

```
public function login()
{
    $recognition = $this->serviceFactory->create('Recognition');
    if ( $recognition->hasAuthenticationError() )
    {
        header('Location: /login');
    }

    if ( $recognition->hasChangedState() ) //was POST, PUT or DELETE call
    {
        header('Location: ./');
    }
}

public function render()
{
    // .. make the html/json/whatever
}
```

Something like this .. that's my 2 cents. Honestly, how you implement the view is entirely up to you.

Comment: @tereško How do you deal with serviceFactory when you need to create objects with it, from different namespaces? Or do you put all service classes in the same folder, always?